# Impersonate Windows User with AntiForgery Tokens

Tags: c#, .net, security, asp.net-web-api, csrf

I have two Web API's; one that is public and one that is internal. I want the public one to communicate with the internal one. However, I'd like two layers of security for the internal one:

- Windows Authentication (which is done)
- AntiForgery tokens (which is what I'm having trouble with)

Right now I'm generating the `AntiForgery` token in the public API:

```
string cookieToken, formToken;
AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
return cookieToken + ":" + formToken;
```

I then pull those off in a filter in the internal API:

```
var request = actionContext.Request;
if (!request.RequestUri.PathAndQuery.StartsWith("/api"))
{
    return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK));
}

string cookieToken = "";
string formToken = "";

IEnumerable<string> tokenHeaders;
if (request.Headers.TryGetValues("RequestVerificationToken", out tokenHeaders))
{
    string[] tokens = tokenHeaders.First().Split(':');
    if (tokens.Length == 2)
    {
        cookieToken = tokens[0].Trim();
        formToken = tokens[1].Trim();
    }
}

try
{
    AntiForgery.Validate(cookieToken, formToken);
}
catch (HttpAntiForgeryException ex)
{
    return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
}

return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK));
```

This works, kind of. The error I'm getting is this:

> The provided anti-forgery token was meant for user "", but the current user is "WINDOWS8VM\Michael".

Somehow I need to impersonate the Windows user when **generating the tokens** so that the user's are the same.

One additional problem is that the `CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials` are empty. This is almost certainly because Windows Authentication is not turned on for the public API. However, the application pool has an identity and it would be that identity that I would be looking for.

Comment: If you call one api (internal) from another api (public), why would you want anti-forgery tokens at all?

Comment: The primary reason is to ensure that other internal applications wouldn't be able to leverage this API. The data is exceptionally sensitive. If we just have Windows Authentication then we don't feel that's enough. It may be something we have to settle with, but we'd like to add a bearer of some sort and we wanted to start by trying to use `AntiForgery` tokens. There are of course other ways, but they are more involved as far as the architecture goes.

Comment: Are you sure you really understand what are you trying to achieve with AF tokens here? Those tokens are to prevent CSRF attacks, not to protect requests between services. The way you want to use them is completely against to what they are designed for. You basically passing bunch of encrypted data from service A to service B and check if B knows the decryption key, but then no AF is needed to do such things.

Comment: @Evk, it is correct that I want to simply pass a key between the services. I was just hoping I'd be able to leverage AF tokens to do it instead of building out that architecture.

Comment: Well you can use only the encryption part of AF, skipping everything else (which is irrelevant for your task anyway). Just use MachineKey.Protect (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.machinekey.protect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to encrypt arbitrary data with the same key AF token would use, and MachineKey.Unprotect to decrypt. Note that AF token also contains "arbitrary data" for your case. If not sure what to encrypt - encrypt the request data itself, then you also will be sure request was not forged in the middle.

Comment: @Evk add your last comment as an answer. I'm going to be implementing that right there. Great idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you just want to verify that your internal api is called by a trusted caller (that is - public api) - you do not need to use anti-forgery tokens. Instead you can use the same mechanism which AF tokens use to encrypt\sign your own data at public api, then decrypting and verifying this data is what you expect at internal api. For that you can use [MachineKey.Protect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.machinekey.protect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [MachineKey.Unprotect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.machinekey.unprotect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods.

If you would do this, note that keys which would be used for encryption *might* differ per application. Look at description of [machineKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8h3skw9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) element, and note the effect of `IsolateApps` setting. If your machine key is configured with `IsolateApps` - one IIS application won't be able to decrypt data protected by another (same story with AF tokens), even if they both located at the same machine.

Also note that if apps are not isolated in this regard, any IIS application on the same machine will be able to encrypt data with the same key and call your internal api. But if you only want to protect your api from another machines in your network - that should be fine enough.

If you are not sure which data to encrypt - combine all sensitive data from the request itself, hash it and Protect that hash. Then at internal api combine the same data, hash it, Unprotect data received from caller and ensure that unprotected data matches target hash.

Comment: These two web applications are going to be on different machines. If the machine keys were the same they would be able to encrypt and decrypt successfully right?

Comment: Yes, as an option you can just explicitly set those keys to the same values on both machines (see machineKey link in answer).

Comment: Okay I think that's going to work pretty well because only those two machines would be in sync. That's effectively exactly what we want!

Comment: I've added the `machineKey` attribute to `system.web` in both `Web.config` files. They have the same values for `validation`, `validationKey`, and `decryptionKey`. However, I keep getting the error `Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.` during decryption. Did I miss something?

Comment: Does your exact same code works if you Protect and Unprotect on the same machine?

Comment: Right now it's actually on the same machine because I'm in development and running both projects through VS. they're running on IIS Express.

Comment: What happens if you try to protect and immediatly unportect in the next statement? Also try to set <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" /> or   <machineKey compatibilityMode="Framework45" />, maybe that is the reason.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110426/discussion-between-mike-perrenoud-and-evk).